# TortoiseSVN on Windows 8 can't commit

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, commit

The situation:

I reinstalled my PC and installed Windows 8. I also installed the latest version of TortoiseSVN. My files are on another (Ubuntu) PC on my network, so windows sees that drive as a network drive.

The problem:

TortoiseSVN sees the directory as an svn repository, no problem there. I can choose commit, enter a comment and choose which files to commit and such. Works all as expected. But once I click the commit button, nothing happens. I mean the commit screen appears, but that's it. Nothing happens after that.

This setup used to work perfectly when my PC was still running on Vista.

Does anybody has any ideas on what may cause this? Cheers!

Comment: `TortoiseSVN sees the directory as an svn repository`... So *repository* or *working copy*?

Comment: Sorry, a working copy, I formulated it wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Issue #1: Accessing a working copy across a network share is not supported, and is generally discouraged.

Issue #2: If your working copy was created/last used with a version of TortoiseSVN (or any other client) which is *not* 1.7.x, then it is not compatible with the latest release. You must manually upgrade each working copy with `svn upgrade` on the command line, or right-click   -> Tortoise SVN -> Upgrade in Windows. But this will render the working copy unusable for older versions...so if you're using that WC from Ubuntu as well, you need to upgrade your client(s) there as well. Which goes back to issue #1 - sharing a WC can get messy.

Comment: Issue #1: thanks for the input, I really should consider using only Ubuntu then to manage my svn

Comment: Issue #2: I was already using 1.7 so that can't be the issue. Are there no logs to be found somewhere where I can see at which point the commit fails?

Comment: Ok, I did an update, followed by a clean, of my working copy. Both went through without a hitch! Then, I tried another commit and just left it open in the background, for once again nothing seemed to happen. But after an hour or so, the commit suddenly went through! Still no idea what might be the problem that is delaying a commit by an hour or so.